# Would it be of interest to create a new category of questions; "Would this idea improve a movie/story"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I often see movies and read stories that seem to have the possibility of improvement if either things happened differently or additional scenes/information were provided.

If this is something that would be permitted, I have a few such ideas.

Comment: On the main site this would be too open-ended, but you're more than welcome to share your ideas in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe), where they might be able to inspire an interesting discussion outside of the constraints of SE answerability.

Comment: The answer is almost always "yes". At least in my head, as applied to my ideas.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, but the sort of open-ended wishy-washy questions you're describing **absolutely wouldn't be a good fit for SFF:SE,** nor any other site in the network other than maybe [Writers:SE.](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) (but don't tell them *I* sent you).

What you're talking about are the very definition of '[bad subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)', where there's no right answer and any answers that get posted are liable to lead to unhelpful debate and contradiction.

Per the [FAQ](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help);

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> **Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require
>   extended discussion.** This is not a discussion board, this is a place
>   for questions that can be answered!

---

Answer (score 1):

*Some* of these questions, if properly elucidated and specific enough, are on-topic on [Writers.SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  However, they are more targeted at things which you are *actually planning to write* rather than speculation about what somebody else could have hypothetically written.  That said, they do seem open to [fan-fiction questions](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction).  If you're asking because you want to write a fanfic, that stack may be a good fit for you.

In principle, you could also take this sort of idea-generation over to [Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but again you should ensure that your question is specific and well-researched.